# How to send persisted complex object from component to another while router navigate in angular 5

Tags: angular5

I need to pass a complex object from component 1 to component 2 while router navigate. Here my object consist of a list of integer values and two integer fields. The  list of integer values are obtained when user selected on the grid. And navigate to component 2 when user click on the button. I have used behavior subject to transfer the data and it is working. Problem is that data become null when page (compoent2) is refreshing in browser.

here is my service

```
export class CustomDataService {

 constructor() {}
 private customData$: BehaviorSubject < any > = new BehaviorSubject < any > (null);

 setData(data: any) {
     this.studentSerachData$.next(data);
 }

 getData() {
     if (this.customData$: getValue()) {
         return this.customData$: asObservable().share();
     }
 }
```

I have added this service in my shared module's provider array and imported this module in component 1 and component 2. I am getting data on component 2 when page load first time. When I refresh the route I am getting **undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get rid of this problem is to send your object via Queryparams , so on page refresh you wont lose the data, but if you are not a fan of queryparams and long urls so try to add your object to Localstorage so after first time you would read it from localStorage , but this way you cant have your object if you come from outside of your project or anywhere else that didnt trigger the behavior subject transfer.

**Option 1** :

```
let params = {};
params[object]=JSON.stringify(objectyouwanttohaveincomponent2)
this.router.navigate(['whatevercomponent2Routeis'], {queryParams: params});
```

Then in ngOninit of component 2 :

```
object : any = {} ;
constructor(private router: Router,
            private route: ActivatedRoute){}
ngoninit(){
this.object = JSON.parse(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('object'));
}
```

**Option 2 :**

After you getData you simply add it to localStorage and you retrive it next time :

```
localStorage.setItem('object',customData$);

ngoninit(){
    if (localStorage.getItem('object')) {
        this.object = localStorage.getItem('object');
    }
}
```